# Using closure to achieve private instance variable effect in Python

Tags: python, class

I am new to Python class. Is using closure to make instance variable private a bad practice? The following code does the job of hiding instance property. Are there other ways?

```
def Person(name, age):
    name, age = name, age
    class Person:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def get_name(self):
            return name
        def get_age(self):
            return age
    return Person()

person = Person("Jane", 22) 
print(person.name)  # print(person.name) # AttributeError, person doens't have attribute "name"
print(person.get_name())  # prints "Jane"
```

Comment: I've never seen this before. Usually I put an underscore before a name that is intended to be private. While Python doesn't actually enforce it, at least it throws up a warning sign if the field is used outside the class.

Comment: As a programmer, I'm annoyed when I encounter this kind of thing.  One of the beauties of Python is that I can modify the behavior at will, and this prevents that reuse.  You can use the `__getattr__` and  `__setattr__` methods to manage property visibility.

Comment: This approach means that there will be an entirely separate copy of the `Person` class object in memory for each instance you create.  You won't be able to use `isinstance()` or similar tests, because no two objects inherit the same class.

Comment: that is bad practice. Use @property. and forget about 'private', because that does not exist in python.

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs- [private variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

So in this case you could change the attributes to have dunder names:

```
class Person(name, age):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age
```

In my opinion though, privacy in Python is more of a best effort practice, and as such you shouldn't attempt too hard to achieve it. The name mangling becomes very awkward should you ever look to do inheritance, and in my experience just causes more headaches than value added.

Going with a single underscore clearly denotes the intended audience of the attribute, and if users are accessing these attributes then they should not expect to continue working should you choose to refactor internal implementation details.

> Is using closure to make instance variable private a bad practice?

One downside to the approach you choose is that every call to `def Person` creates a new class definition, which will only be used to construct a single instance. In doing so you also lose the ability to introspect the class with methods like `isinstance(obj, Person)`, and also create a lot of garbage data in your code, slowing it down.

Also because the class definition is dynamic, you do not provide sufficient information for static analysis tools to validate proper usage of your class instances (such as mypy).

Additionally, this doesn't even solve the issue of true privacy, because in the original example it is still possible to access the values of your closure:

```
>>> Person("bob", 23).get_name.__closure__[0].cell_contents
'bob'
```

Even more malicious:

```
>>> person = Person("bob", 23)
>>> person.get_name.__closure__[0].cell_contents = 'alice'
>>> person.get_name()
'alice'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the hassles in trying to achieve inheritance. You code under "more malicious" give me more things to read about